# Can you take off your custom skin's layers in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can you take off your custom skin's layers in Minecraft Pocket Edition while in game?

I have looked through all the categories in the settings menu and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? If you explain why in more detail, I can possibly help you find a way around it that would work best for you

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think this is possible.

In Java Edition, you can upload a skin to a website like [Novaskin.me](http://Novaskin.me) to remove layers. In Bedrock edition, it does not allow customizing skins outside what is available in the store.